# How do I keep a SQL Server Profiler trace from jumping to the bottom entry?

Tags: sql-server, profiler, trace

When monitoring a trace in SQL Server Profiler, is there a way to prevent it from jumping to the most recent event without pausing the trace?

I'm often trying to scroll up and read descriptions of events, and as a new one comes in, it jumps to the bottom.

Comment: Nevermind...just found the setting.  Window>Auto-Scroll

Comment: can you post that in the answer box a'd accept it instead of a comment?

Answer (score 2):

Simple Answer :

From the toolbar, select `Window>Auto Scroll`